# KendoUI: Adding Grid Aggregates with HTML Helper in MVC4

Tags: kendo-ui

I am trying to add a sum aggregate in the HTML helper for the grid, but am not sure how to add it for the Total field in this example. This is my simple example:

```
   @(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model).Name("Grid") 
      .Pageable()
      .Sortable()
      .Scrollable()
      .Filterable()
      .Columns(columns =>
          {
              columns.Bound(p => p.FirstName);
              columns.Bound(p => p.LastName);
              columns.Bound(p => p.Email);
              columns.Bound(p => p.Total).ClientFooterTemplate("Sum: $#= sum #");
          })
      .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
          .Ajax()
          .Read(read => read.Action("Users_Read", "Home"))

      ))
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are not defining the `aggregate` in the `DataSource`:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model).Name("Grid") 
  .Columns(columns =>
      {
          columns.Bound(p => p.FirstName);
          columns.Bound(p => p.LastName);
          columns.Bound(p => p.Email);
          columns.Bound(p => p.Total).FooterTemplate("Sum: #= sum #");
      })
  .DataSource(dataSource => 
               dataSource.Ajax()
                         .Read(read => read.Action("Users_Read", "Home"));
                 .Aggregates(aggregates => { aggregates.Add(p => p.Total).Sum(); } )
                 .ServerOperation(false) 
  ))
```

Comment: should this same sample apply to datasource.Server as well? (possibly without the .Read call...?)

Comment: ...because it doesn't seem to working. just renders an empty footer row, so i'm just using jquery to get the sum and place it in the cell

Comment: I had to add a .ServerOperation(false) in the datasource.

Comment: @OnaBai: I just edited this, as I'm having the same problem and ServerOperation(false) was the only way I got this to work. But I see you're using FooterTemplate here, and I had to use ClientFooterTemplate. I'm concerned I ended up a bit beyond my knowledge even though I got this working, so feel free to roll that one back.

Answer (score 4):

This should work
    `.FooterTemplate(@<text>Total Count: @item.Sum</text>)`