# Kendo Grid Aggregate Sum Displaying always 0

Tags: ajax, json, kendo-grid, addition, aggregate-functions

I have Combobox event that call ajax function to fill grid datasource.
i can see my grid correctly filled but aggregate Sum display always 0.
What can i do?

**AJAX call**

```
    $.ajax({
     url: '@Url.Action("CreaGrid3", "Sales")',
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    data: { bra: brand, mod: model, prj: project, ver: version, rel: release },
    success: function (result) {
     var grid = $("#Grid3").data("kendoGrid");
    var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
       data: result.Data
    });
    grid.setDataSource(dataSource);
    grid.dataSource.read();
}
```

**Here my view:**

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<IndSudUI.Models.TabTemp3>()
    .Name("Grid3")
    .Columns(columns =>
    {

        columns.Bound(e => e.DESCRIZIONE);
        columns.Bound(e => e.Totale)
            .Format("{0:C3}")
            .ClientFooterTemplate("Sum: #=sum#");

    })
    .Pageable()
    .Sortable()
    .Scrollable()
    .Resizable(resize => resize.Columns(true))
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Ajax()
        .Aggregates(a =>
        {
            a.Add(p => p.Totale).Sum();
        })
        .ServerOperation(false)
     )

    .Events(events => events.DataBound("onDataBound5"))
)
```

**Here my Controller**

I removed some parts of code that are not relevant

```
public JsonResult CreaGrid3([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, string bra, string mod, string prj, string ver, string rel)
            {

    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(bra))
                    bra = bra.Trim();
                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(mod))
                    mod = mod.Trim();
                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(prj))
                    prj = prj.Trim();
                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(ver))
                    ver = ver.Trim();
                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(rel))
                    rel = Convert.ToDateTime(rel.Trim()).ToString("yyyyMMdd");

                try
                {


                    List<TabTemp3> Listed = new List<TabTemp3>();
                    var connection = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
                    DataTable dt = new DataTable();

                    string sqlcmd = "SELECT l.DESCRIZIONE, CASE WHEN m.PezziTurnoStd=0 THEN 0 ELSE (8 / CONVERT(decimal, m.PezziTurnoStd)) * pr.CostoOraDir * m.PersonaleDirettoStd END Totale FROM ";
                    sqlcmd = sqlcmd + "AHE.dbo.Inds0DbParArt AS m INNER JOIN ";
//... ETC ...
                    using (var dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlcmd, connection))
                    {
                        dataAdapter.Fill(dt);
                    }
                    foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
                    {
                        Listed.Add(new TabTemp3
                        {
                            DESCRIZIONE = row["DESCRIZIONE"].ToString(),
                            Totale = (decimal)(row["Totale"])

                        });
                    }
                    var temp = Listed.AsEnumerable<TabTemp3>();

                    return Json(temp.ToDataSourceResult(request), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("" + e);
                }
                return null;

            }
```

Comment: I don't see anywhere where you are populating the Model Property "sum". This code `.ClientFooterTemplate("Sum: #=sum#");` is looking for a property named 'sum' for that particular row

Comment: I following the [link](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/grid/aggregates) example, @CSharper. What's wrong?

Comment: take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13536668/kendoui-adding-grid-aggregates-with-html-helper-in-mvc4

Comment: @CSharper: i have just insert the aggregate function in my view.